# MVC.Net, Ajax.BeginForm, jQuery, and IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, ajax.beginform

I'm trying to use the "standard" MVC.Net unobtrusive JavaScript AJAX pattern as described here:

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-ajax.html

More specifically, the pattern might look like this:

//In the VIEW

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("action1", "controller1",
    null,
    new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnSuccess = "successHandler",
    },
    new { id = "formId" }
    ))
{

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ModelItem)
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
}
```

I believe I've set up the necessary elements in Web.Config, along with what appears to be working jQuery code. The "action1" method on the controller is set to return a JsonResult, perhaps like this:

//In the responding CONTROLLER (and using a MODEL not important here)

```
    public JsonResult action1(MyModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Json(new { statusCode = 1 });
        }

        return Json(new { statusCode = 0 });
    }
```

This pattern works great when I use "modern" browsers; that is, the latest versions from the three major vendors. However, when I attempt to do anything with Internet Explorer 8 (and presumably before), I receive a "File Download - Security Warning" dialog box. I believe this dialog box pops up because the browser doesn't know how to handle the content-type produced by a JsonResult (application/json), and so prompts the user to save the return value instead. However, changing the content type in the JsonResult method to, say, "text/plain" or "text/html", doesn't work either. Instead,  IE8 redirects the browser window to display the raw JSON sent back. Neither of these behaviors works for me.

I have the sense that the problem stems from the top, which is to say that the "ajaxification" of an Ajax.BeginForm form simply doesn't happen in IE8, but I could be wrong, and in any case, I don't know what to do about it.

Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: After further testing, it appears that I'm having this issue only with <FORM>s that are added to the page after initial load. They are built using the above code pattern, however. It may be the case that I need to tell IE8 to parse the form in some fashion after load. Could the reason more advanced browsers work be a JavaScript live() function?